# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Route:

```
Route::get('/blog/page/{slug?}', 'BlogController@page')->name('page');
```

Controller:

```
 public function page($slug) {
            $pages = Page::all();
            return view('blog.pages', [
                'pages' => $pages,
                'page' => Page::where('slug', $slug)->first(),
            ]);
        }
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title'){{$page->meta_title}}@endsection
@section('meta_keyword'){{$page->meta_keyword}}@endsection
@section('meta_description'){{$page->meta_description}}@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>{{$page->title}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Model:

```
// Mass assigned
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'title', 'slug', 'published', 'meta_title', 'meta_description', 'meta_keyword', 'published', 'created_by', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'modified_by'];

    // Mutators
    public function setSlugAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug( mb_substr($this->title, 0, 40) . "-" . \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('dmyHi'), '-');
    }
```

По итогу ошибка

```
Trying to get property 'meta_title' of non-object (View: /home/srb/dev/vr/resources/views/blog/pages.blade.php)
```

Столбец в БД создан и заполнен. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Если во view все записать как {{$page->meta_title or ""}}, то на странице не выводятся переменные.

Comment: Не нужно выкладывать текст ошибки на стороннем ресурсе, добавьте его в свой вопрос в текстовом виде.

Comment: Окей, исправил.

Comment: из очевидного - `Page::where('slug', $slug)->first()` возвращает `null`

Comment: Как корректно записать что бы достать из базы страницу?